# Tensorflow estimator keeps creating devices

Tags: tensorflow

I have a custom estimator for a two-layer neural network and I want to extract validation set performance every epoch to control early stopping. I'm using TensorFlow 1.41 and I am running on 3 970 GTX GPUs. My estimator looks like this (in future I want to customize the architecture in my network so I cannot use an off-the-shelf estimator) :

```
def my_estimator(features, labels, mode, params):
""" NN estimator function """

# set up regularizer
regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=params["l2_lambda"])
drop_rate = scale=params["dropout"]

# input layer will just be features
input_layer = features

# Hidden fully connected layer with n_hidden_1 neurons
layer_1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs = input_layer,units= n_hidden_1, activation = tf.nn.relu, kernel_regularizer=regularizer)

# droupout for Hidden 1
dropout_1 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=layer_1, rate=drop_rate,
                              training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

# Hidden fully connected layer with n_hidden_2 neurons
layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs = dropout_1,units= n_hidden_2, activation = tf.nn.relu,kernel_regularizer=regularizer)

# droupout for Hidden 2
dropout_2 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=layer_2, rate=drop_rate,
                              training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

# Output fully connected layer with p neurons
output_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputs = dropout_2,units= p, activation= None,kernel_regularizer=regularizer)

# Reshape output layer to 1-dim Tensor to return predictions
predictions = tf.reshape(output_layer, [-1])

predictions_dict = {"predictions": predictions}

# If prediction mode, early return
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions_dict)

# Calculate loss using mean squared error
objective_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(tf.reshape(labels, [-1]), predictions)
reg_losses = tf.cast(tf.losses.get_regularization_loss(),tf.float32)
loss = objective_loss+ reg_losses

# add eval metric ops
eval_metric_ops = {"rmse": tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(tf.reshape(labels, [-1]), predictions),
                   "mae": tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(tf.reshape(labels, [-1]), predictions)}

# build tranning op
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(params["learning_rate"], tf.train.get_global_step(),
                                       100, 0.96, staircase=True)

gdoptim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
train_op =gdoptim.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
grads_and_vars = gdoptim.compute_gradients(loss)
grad_norms = [tf.nn.l2_loss(g) for g, v in grads_and_vars]
grad_norm = tf.add_n(grad_norms)

# add some additional information to the summary writer
tf.summary.scalar("cost", objective_loss)              
tf.summary.scalar("reg_cost", reg_losses)          
tf.summary.scalar("grad_norm", grad_norm)
tf.summary.scalar("learningrate", learning_rate)
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions, loss, train_op, eval_metric_ops)
```

I am training as follows:

```
nn = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=my_estimator, params=model_params,config=run_config)
# for each training epoch:
for i in range(training_epochs):
    nn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,steps=num_batches)
    val_result = nn.evaluate(input_fn=eval_val_input_fn)
    # decide to break based on val_result
```

train_input_fn is a tf.Dataset iterator that moves in batches while eval_val_input_fn traverses a much smaller set in 1 batch. The data is all continuous features and the labels are scalars (it's a regression task). The issue I have is that my output is flooded with hundreds of instances of device creation:

```
2018-01-29 17:33:49.721025: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2018-01-29 17:33:49.721047: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:2) -> (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2018-01-29 17:33:49.854761: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2018-01-29 17:33:49.854793: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2018-01-29 17:33:49.854811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:2) -> (device: 2, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2018-01-29 17:33:50.260143: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2018-01-29 17:33:50.260177: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:1) -> (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:02:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
```

tf.Estimators seem to hide a lot of information about the session and graph from the user. I do not think it is necessary to create the devices so many times - surely this can be done in one session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call estimator.train, it starts a new session and reloads weights from checkpoint. Thus, it keeps creating new sessions and devices.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a different workflow I should use that avoids this? Can I not force the session to stay open?

Comment: I think you cannot avoid that. It is better to implement evaluation via hooks.